# A cookie header was received that contained an invalid cookie.

Tags: java, tomcat, networking, cookies, web

I am **migrating** my Server from **Tomcat-6** to **Tomcat-9**. My website is designed for the protocol of HTTP/1.1 . The server.xml file contains the Connector Protocol of **org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol** . The server starts up normally without generating any errors. However, when I try to access my website using localhost, I get the following error :-

INFO [https-nio-8445-exec-3] **org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Cookie.logInvalidHeader** A cookie header was received [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 21, 22, 23]; userId=53136] that contained an invalid cookie. That cookie will be ignored.Note: further occurrences of this error will be logged at DEBUG level.

Can anyone please tell me the reason for this error?
What causes an invalid cookie?
Can this error be avoided if I use a different connector?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am getting the same error

Comment: No, I haven't solved it yet. I could not get an answer for it anywhere, hence the migration is pending.

Comment: We hit the issue on Apache Tomcat 8.5

Comment: Your cookies is rejected by the newer Tomcat's CookieProcessor. Possible solutions are: (1) Change your cookie to the compatible one. (2) Configure your Tomcat to use the old LegacyCookieProcessor. (3). Halt the upgrade. [References: (a) https://stackoverflow.com/a/38705982/1878585 . (b) http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html#Cookies . (c) https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/cookie-processor.html#Standard_Implementation ]

Comment: Is there a way to disable this logging as the cookie might contain sensitive data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the API deployed on tomcat able to grab the cookies when I send a cURL request, though there was tomcat warning.

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  --cookie "userId=64ad960c-bb7e-48dd-8191-4f31539bc2c2,accessToken=64ad960c-bb7e-48dd-8191-4f31539bc2c2" -d '{"message":"play porcupine tree"}' http://localhost:9090/nlu/convo
```

**But** to remove the warning, had to update cookie processor (`LegacyCookieProcessor`) in the tomcat config (`conf/context.xml`)

Example,

```
cat /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.12/conf/context.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!--
    <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor" />
    -->

    <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor" />

</Context>
```

I thought `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor` would work but did not, `LegacyCookieProcessor` is required.

### Reference

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/cookie-processor.html#Legacy_Cookie_Processor_-_org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265

> `LegacyCookieProcessor` implements a strict interpretation of the cookie specifications.
> Due to various interoperability issues with browsers not all strict
> behaviours are enabled by default and additional options are available
> to further relax the behaviour of this cookie processor if required.

Answer (score 7):

i was getting this issue with spring boot of version above 2.2.x

it got fixed after adding below bean

```
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> cookieProcessorCustomizer() {
    return tomcatServletWebServerFactory -> tomcatServletWebServerFactory.addContextCustomizers((TomcatContextCustomizer) context -> {
      context.setCookieProcessor(new LegacyCookieProcessor());
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw: I somehow got my Chrome browser into a really b0rken state, getting it to send a malformed cookie with mismatched quotes: `"XSRF-TOKEN=93926112-aa12-440e-8e06-02b7fbce27d5;`

Just clearing the cookie from the developer tools wasn't sufficient, but `Clear storage` from the sidebar of the `Application` tab seems to have done it.